Will 2024 characters be incompatible with a 5e campaign?
I did see this question but it's slightly different from mine. The question being answered there is whether you can have 2014 characters in a 2024 campaign. My question is the reverse. Can you have 2024 characters in a 2014 campaign?
I'm running a game on 5e, but my players have chosen pregens that were created from the 2024 rules. Will this be an issue? Should I ask them to recreate those characters using 5e?

How is this a different question than the one you link? That question doesn't even say it's about a 2024 campaign, and at the time it was asked they couldn't run a 2024 campaign (the rules changes hadn't been published yet); the implication was that it was a 2014 campaign that might want to allow characters generated under the 2024 rules, which is exactly what you're asking.

@ShadowRanger None of the answers address my question. All of them are talking about whether 5e characters can be used in a 2024 game

Hi there Student! Welcome to the stack.
It's a bit nit-picky, but we've kind of been round and round the houses on this, so I'm going to point out that the 2014 rules and the 2024 rules are both still "5e". I can see you have the right tags to point this out, but you might consider editing your question to make it clearer.
